# Let $\mathfrak T_X = \{f^{-1} (U) : U \in \mathfrak T_Y\}$ then $\mathfrak T_X$ is a topology on X. False?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $f :X \rightarrow Y$ be a function and suppose that $\mathfrak T_Y$ is a topology on $Y$.  Let $\mathfrak T_X = \{f^{-1} (U) : U \in \mathfrak T_Y\}$ then $\mathfrak T_X$ is a topology on X.

$f^{-1}(U)$ refers to the inverse image of a set

I am supposed to determine if this is true or false and then prove or give a counterexample. I am leaning towards this being a false statement because this conjecture doesn't say anything about the function being continuous but I am not sure if this is necessary.  Can anyone help with where to go with my thinking?

Comment: If $\mathfrak{T}_X$ is a topology, then $f$ will be continuous with respect to $\mathfrak{T}_X$ and $\mathfrak{T}_Y$. But that's not the point. You need to check whether the family $\mathfrak{T}_X$ of subsets of $X$ satisfies the conditions for a topology. So you need to check whether $\varnothing \in \mathfrak{T}_X$, $X\in \mathfrak{T}_X$ etc.

Comment: Without having a topology, there isn't a notion of a continuous function. The best place to start is with the definition of a topology and the properties of preimages with respect to union and intersection.

Answer (score 1):

First ask yourself what does it mean for function $f:X\to Y$ to be continuous? It is defined that for every open subset $U$ of $Y$ we will have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is a open subset of $X$. But if we didn't defined yet a topology on $X$ how can we even refer to the continuity of $f$?

In the claim, what comes in to question is whether $\mathfrak T_X$ defines a topology on $X$ and not whether $f$ is continuous. note that if it is a topology then indeed $f$ will be continuous. Another fact is, that $\mathfrak T_X$ would have been the most coarser (or least finer) topology on $X$ such that $f$ would have been continues.

so try to see weather $\mathfrak T_X$ satisfy the definition of a topology. and say if you need more help.

---

We would like to show the following:

1) $X,\emptyset\in\mathfrak T_X$

2) if $\{U_a\}_{a\in I}\subseteq\mathfrak T_X$ for some idex set $I$, then $\cup _{a\in I}U_a$

3) if $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n\subseteq\mathfrak T_X$ then $\cap_{i=1}^nU_i\in\mathfrak T_X$

For (1) it is immediate that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ and $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$.

For (2) and (3) you will want to prove two identities about functions.

a) $f^{-1}(\cup _{a\in I}U_a)=\cup_{a\in I} f^{-1}(U_a)$

b)  $f^{-1}(\cap _{i=1}^nU_i)=\cap_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(U_i)$

and from here I hope that the rest of the proof is clear to you.

Note that the collection of $U_a$'s need not be in $\mathfrak T_X$ for those two identities to hold.

Comment: I would appreciate some more help.  I know I need to check the 3 conditions now.  First the whole set and the empty set.  How would I start by doing that

Comment: i added more explanations to my answer. hope it will do :)

Comment: I have a similar question but it is not at all clear to me how to prove or disprove 2) and 3).  Can you clarify?

Comment: @NUG, the properties 1,2,3 are the definition of a topology, so if we want to prove that $\mathfrak T _X$ is a topology then we have to prove them. and it should be relatively easy to do so, by using the identities $a$ and $b$. Look over the definition of $\mathfrak T _X$, the identities show us that it is closed under unions and finite intersections.